# How to extract "generic" code from "client-specific" code from a git repo?

Tags: git

I developed an admin panel, which was designed for a specific client. Now, the project requirements demand, that non-client-specific code should be extracted as a **separate git branch** to serve as a basis for the new client-specific variations of the project.

**TL;DR**

My goal, as I already mentioned, is to:

1. Extract the client specific code from my existing project as a standalone branch.
2. Commit all the "Generic" features/bugfixes to the generic branch in the future.
3. Merge changes from the generic branch to client-specific branches.

The problem occurs once I extract the client-specific code, remove all the client-specific features from that branch, apply some new commits and attempt to merge it to the former branch (the client specific one):

[image]

As you see, the problem is, that `generic-branch` applies non-desireable changes like commit "1" to the `client-branch`.

So the question is: what would be a proper way of extracting the generic features from the existing repository **for a purpose of branching different client-specific branches from it** in the future?

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: @I've updated the question and yes, I make a living working as a master-illustrator ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you extract non client specific code and create commit (`commit-1`) from it, you need to merge this commit back to client specific branch. As this merge should not change content of client specific branch, you should use `ours` merge strategy:

```
git checkout client-branch
git merge -s ours commit-1
```

The effective result of this merge is that following merge of `generic-branch` into `client-branch` will consider `commit-1` as merge base.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You need to cherry-pick the commit 2 instead of merge the generic-branch into client-branch:

```
git checkout client-branch

git cherry-pick <commit-2>
```

Comment: This way, every time I submit a bugfix or a new feature to `generic-branch` I will need to use cherry-picking every single time to apply the changes to the `client-branch`. This is not an option